# About the meaning of "the"

Tags: grammar, articles

Going to work by bike is good for environment.

Playing sports is good for health.

Do you think that "the" is needed before "environment" and "health"?

Answer (score 2):

*The environment* in the sense of 'the natural world in general' is always used with the definite article (as distinct from particular kinds such as *a woodland environment*).

As for your second sentence, *good for your health* would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Google [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=good+for+the+health%2C+good+for+health%2C+good+for+your+health&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgood%20for%20the%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgood%20for%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgood%20for%20your%20health%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgood%20for%20the%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgood%20for%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgood%20for%20your%20health%3B%2Cc0) shows that "good for **the** health" has been used quite consistently, overtaken by others in about 1990.

Answer (score 0):

> Going to work by bike is good for environment.

In this case I would use "the", as in; "Going to work by bike is good for the environment."

> Playing sports is good for health.

In this case, it might be best to specify who's health is improved by playing sports, for example "Playing sports is good for your health" or "Playing sports is good for one's health."

Either should work, but using health on it's own is a bit vague.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Vagueness has nothing to do with it. A determiner is required here.

Comment: The primary purpose of a determiner is what? To determine or decide something, thus clarifying vagueness, so then how does vagueness have "nothing to do with it". I suggested a possessive determiner for this exact reason.

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't say anything about *why* you would use the definite article with *environment*.  If you explain the reasoning behind answers, they will be much stronger.